# Inconsistent behavior after isExternalStorageManager() = true in Android 11

Tags: android-external-storage, android-11, preferencescreen

I added a Preference button in my PreferenceScreen to call for `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION` in Android 11:

```
        prefn.setOnPreferenceClickListener(arg0 -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        });

        if (Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
            pref.setSummary("Allowed");
        } else {
            pref.setSummary("Not Allowed");
        }
```

When I change the setting from `Allow` to `Not allow` and the setting screen is closed, the PreferenceScreen is reloaded (in particular, the `onCreate()`), and the pref summary changes to "Not Allowed", as expected. However, if I click and change the setting from `Not allow` to `Allow`, it is not reloaded, and the summary still shows "Not allowed" despite the fact that the setting is in the `Allow` state. Even stranger, if I change 3 times, `Not allow` to `Allow` to `Not allow` to `Allow`, it is reloaded and the summary shows "Allowed", as it should.

Any clue?? I tried calling `startActivityForResult` without success.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a solution, but a workaround. And a coward one, sorry.

Simply fix the thing through the `onResume()` method of the Preference activity. Namely, before calling `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION`, set a variable:

```
lastManagerPerm = Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
```

and then in the `onResume()`:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30 && !lastManagerPerm && Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
         prefn.setSummary("Allowed");
         ....
    }
}
```